# PgAdmin4 cant find pgagent as an extension MacOS

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, pgagent

I installed pgagent using EnterpriseDB's installer on MacOS. However, pgagent doesn't show up in pgadmin after the installation. Even when I try to manually add pgagent as an extension, I get the error: extension "pgagent" is not available and that pgadmin "Could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/postgresql/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory"

Here are the installed pgagent files inside the mentioned directory, so I don't understand why it's not recognizing it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmRMA.png)

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both postgresql and pgagent but none of them helped.

Comment: If the installation is successful then pgAdmin will automatically show pgAgent. No need to add the extension manually.